# Draw arrows from one part of a sentence to another

Tags: arrows, nodes, text

I'm trying to get the text in the top line to be laid out like the text in the bottom line. Ultimately, I need to draw arrows from the coloured t's to the word 'when'. I thought that specifying the nodes as I did in the code would be the easiest way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[white, text=black] (1,1) node(when){When};
\draw[white, text=black] (when) node[anchor=west](s1){did John say};
\draw[white, text=red] (s1) node[anchor=west](t1){t};
\draw[white, text=black] (t1) node[anchor=west](s2){that Pat was fired};
\draw[white, text=blue] (s2) node[anchor=west](t2){t};
\node (1,-1) {When did John say \textcolor{red}{t} that Pat was fired \textcolor{blue}{t} ?};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you are looking for `tikznode` which acts as a marker for begining or ending such annotations with an arrow -- have a look at the answer below please

Comment: is there something else i can help you with

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to incorporate it successfully into my document. I'll study the code, now, so I can learn how it works.

Comment: you may like to accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \tikznode{PT}When did John say anything
        \item[] John never said anything at \tikznode{PB0}all 
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,cyan,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
        \draw[->] (PT)-- +(0,-0.3) -| (PB0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```